# How to set destination as lambda in cloudformation for aws kinesis data analytics

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I want to create aws kinesis data analytics in cloudformation and I do want to add destination as lambda. 
As the following link suggests:

[aws kinesis data analytics cfn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-kinesisanalytics-application.html)

I can add destionation as follows:

```
  BasicApplicationOutputs:
Type: "AWS::KinesisAnalytics::ApplicationOutput"
DependsOn: BasicApplication
Properties:
  ApplicationName: !Ref BasicApplication
  Output:
    Name: "exampleOutput"
    DestinationSchema:
      RecordFormatType: "CSV"
    KinesisStreamsOutput:
      ResourceARN: !GetAtt OutputKinesisStream.Arn
      RoleARN: !GetAtt KinesisAnalyticsRole.Arn
```

Which I am ok with that and works fine. But this is set to another stream as destination. However I want lambda as destination and I do not know even if cloudformation support it or not. Can anyone shed light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed it is not supported to directly connect analytics to lambda via  cloud-formation so the way to fix it is to use another stream as an brifge